# Faster image upload on mobile

Tags: images

So, for my wordpress mobile site, there is a button to upload an image (either from camera or phone gallery).

However since the size of mobile images are well over 3 MB, it takes too long to upload them.

Is there a way to reduce the image size before the upload even happens? or to speed up the uploading process.

Thank you guys!

Comment: yes there is, but why is this a wordpress specific question?

Comment: It might not be a wordpress specific, but I thought it would be appropriate since my site is wordpress. =P

Comment: Site is only for wordpress specific questions, otherwise any web development question can be described as relating to wordpress in one way or another ;). Your question is a JS question and it is better to ask JS experts for an answer rather then WP experts.

Comment: I see. Should I restart the question on the JS site? Anyway, thanks tho! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/client-side-image-resize/) to reduce file size before the upload.

Comment: right in the plugin description - "This plugin does not work on the iPhone or iPad."

Comment: Your correct.  I did not see that.  I found this other plugin that looks like it works for everything.

Comment: Could you tell me what would that be? thanks! =)

Comment: I checked the imsanity plugin but it looks like it resize uploaded images. I am looking for a way to reduce the image size on the client side (even before uploading happens).

Comment: I am changing my answer hopefully one last time :) I think this plugin does it all and it says it supports IOS and android.  Let me know how it works.